# Is there a way to find out programmatically (C#), if JavaScript is enabled in Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I'm trying to find out in a prerequisite checker tool (written in C#), if Internet Explorer has enabled JavaScript. I don't want to change it ... just read out the information. Is that available somewhere in the registry?

Comment: So, you mean IE is running on the same machine as your C# code? Not a remote client?

Comment: The answer isn't that easy since different security zones may have different settings regarding javascript being active or not.

Comment: Widor: yes. The tool is supposed to check, if all prerequisites for an applications are ok. So it's the same machine - nothing remote.

Comment: flq: Well if I find out, how to check it for one zone, I might be able to figure out, how to check it for other zones :) But I understand, that the answer if JavaScript is enabled, may not be a simple "yes" or "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to know what security zone the website(s) that needs javascript would fall under.

When you know what zone you are looking for you can find it under SOFTWARE\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones...

The parameters are not humanreadable though so you'd need to lookup some information regarding those.

However it all feels a bit sketchy doing it this way
I hope that someone can give you a better answer than mine, at least a simpler.

Comment: Hmm ... I had a look at that, but it seems like the content of that key doesn't change, when I change the JavaScript settings in IE ...

Comment: Ah, could be you're right. I have a vague memory of doing something similar back when I worked as a domain administrator but I might not have remembered it correctly - Sorry

Comment: I have to apologize. I was looking in the wrong place ... Those are settings for CurrentUser of course and not for LocalMachine. You were right Jonas.

Answer (score -1):

I think modernizr is what you're looking for, it enables you to read the supported features from the HTML tag of your web page.

See:
http://www.modernizr.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately that would be JavaScript